# Django models with foreign key relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 Models.

1)Category
2)size

I had 4 Category A,B,C,D

When A category selected,i have to take size = Star,Round
When B category selected,i have to take size in range eg(5 to 7)
then how can i build models for this purpose ??

```
class Category(models.Model)
         cat_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Size(models.Model)
       category=models.ForeignKey(Category)
        size_name=models.CharField()`
```

This works fine in Category A ,but how to store range when Category B

Comment: *models* are *class* not function

Comment: I got my answer.I am resolved my problem by using generic foreign key